# Azure SQL - Correct way to create a contained database user in a non-contained azure sql database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have multiple non-contained `Azure` sql databases.  We plan to create contained database users in each of them.  These users are for SQL Authentication.  My question:  Do these users have to be created in the master database?

Thank you in advance!

Here are the steps I tried:

Scenario 1 where the user is created BUT failed to sign into the server using SSMS.

1. In the application database 
   `CREATE USER someContainedDBUser WITH PASSWORD = 'somepwd';`
2. In the application database, grant roles
3. Attempt to sign in with SSMS ( failure)

Scenario 2 where the user is created and can sign into the server using SSMS.

1. In master database, 
   `CREATE USER someContainedDBUser WITH PASSWORD = 'somepwd';`
2. In the application database,
   `CREATE USER someContainedDBUser WITH PASSWORD = 'somepwd';`
3. In the application database, grant roles
4. Attempt to sign in with SSMS ( success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create them in master also.  You **do** have to specify the database you want to connect to via the Options section in SSMS, eg

[image: Options screen]

Comment: Thank you! That helps clear my confusion.  Is it possible to CREATE USER with a default database?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.  `DEFAULT_DATABASE` is part of the `CREATE LOGIN` syntax intended for creating non-contained users.